# Preventing Overlapping Appointments C# MySQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Not sure how I can make it so when the button is clicked to save/book an appointment, that it will check for existing appointments and not allow appointments to overlap..
Heres the code as it stands.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-ELTMMCE;Initial Catalog=Stylogistx;Integrated Security=True");
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTbx.Text, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            
            if (dt < DateTime.Today)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Appointment Date is in the past. Please select current or future date.");
            }
            else
            {
              
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT(APP_DATE, APP_STARTTIME, APP_ENDTIME, CLIENT_ID, EMP_ID, SERVICE_ID, APP_STATUS) values ('" + dateTbx.Text + "','" + apptStartTimePicker.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt") + "','" + apptEndTimePicker.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt") + "','" + clientCmboBx.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + stylistCmboBx.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + serviceCmboBx.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + "BOOKED" + "')", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Appointment Booked");

                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Track Inventory?", "Would you like to track any inventory for this appointment?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        Inventory_Tracking invt = new Inventory_Tracking();
                        invt.Show();
                    }
                    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        Appointment_Management am = new Appointment_Management();
                        am.Show();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            this.Hide();
```

I tried creating a query selecting appointments where APP_STATUS = 'BOOKED'
Which will pull in APP_STARTTIME and APP_ENDTIME.

Im not sure of a way to check for existing start & end times, and push an invalid message if trying to book an appointment in a time slot that another appointment is booked in.

Im still new to C#/Java, Im stuck and Idk what to do.

Comment: A solution to this would be to create a stored procedure that takes in the start and end time of the appointment as arguments and checks to see if any appointment exists with the same start and end time. If one does exist, it should return an error message indicating that the appointment overlaps. The C# code should then check the return value of the stored procedure, and if it is an error message then it should display it to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your help. @Mech What would that look like?
SELECT APP_DATE, APP_STARTTIME, APP_ENDTIME
FROM APPOINTMENT 
WHERE APP_STATUS = 'BOOKED'

would bring in the relevant data, but Im not sure how to implement this part "checks to see if any appointment exists with the same start and end time. If one does exist, it should return an error message indicating that the appointment overlaps."

Answer (score 0):

```
    I have written some code for you. Try to do the following. -
    1- Create a class model
    2- Serializer class model to XML
    3- Do implementation in your DAL and BAL layers
    4- Create a procedure 
    
    Some code samples:
        public class AppointmentDetails
        {
            public int appDate { get; set; }
            public string appStartTime { get; set; }
            public string appEndTime { get; set; }
            public int clientId { get; set; }
            public int empId { get; set; }
            public int serviceId { get; set; }
            public string appStatus { get; set; }
        }
    
    public void BookAppointmentDetails(AppointmentDetails appointmentDetails)
            {
                string xmlAppointmentDetails = string.Empty;
                //Serializer model to XML
                XmlSerializer mfaAuditSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppointmentDetails));
                using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
                {
                    mfaAuditSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, appointmentDetails);
                    xmlAppointmentDetails = textWriter.ToString();
                }
    
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<<DefineConnection>>"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.uspBookNewAppointmentDetails", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    
                        // set up the parameters
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmAppointmentDetails", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xmlAppointmentDetails;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmOutput", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    
    
                        // open connection and execute stored procedure
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
                        // read output value from @prmOutput
                        string output = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@prmOutput"].Value);
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
    
Create a table and stored the procedure in SQL Server Database
CREATE TABLE AppointmentDetails(
AppId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
APP_DATE DATE NULL,
APP_STARTTIME NVARCHAR(12) NULL,
APP_ENDTIME NVARCHAR(12) NULL,
CLIENT_ID INT NULL,
EMP_ID INT NULL,
SERVICE_ID INT NULL,
APP_STATUS NVARCHAR(20) NULL
)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.PROCEDURES WHERE Name = 'uspBookNewAppointmentDetails')
    BEGIN
        DROP PROC dbo.uspBookNewAppointmentDetails
    END
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspBookNewAppointmentDetails]
    @prmAppointmentDetails XML,
    @prmOutput      [NVARCHAR](20) OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
     BEGIN TRY  
        INSERT INTO AppointmentDetails(APP_DATE,APP_STARTTIME,APP_ENDTIME,CLIENT_ID,EMP_ID,SERVICE_ID,APP_STATUS)
        SELECT
            data.col.value('(appDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
            data.col.value('(appStartTime)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(12)'),
            data.col.value('(appEndTime)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(12)'),
            data.col.value('(clientId)[1]', 'INT'),
            data.col.value('(empId)[1]', 'INT'),
            data.col.value('(serviceId)[1]', 'INT'),
            data.col.value('(appStatus)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)')
        FROM @prmAppointmentDetails.nodes('/BookAppointment') as data(col)
        IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @prmOutput='BOOKED';
        END
      COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
     END TRY      
     BEGIN CATCH      
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]      
      DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX), @ProcessName NVARCHAR(MAX), @ErrorSeverity NVARCHAR(MAX)
      SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
      SET @ProcessName = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
      SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
      SET @prmOutput=@ErrorMessage;
      RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,@ProcessName,@ErrorSeverity)
     END CATCH 
    END
```